# Append XML with XAdES-T Timestamp Response (TSR)

Tags: php, xml, xml-dsig, xades

For a project, XML files are dynamically generated. After a while, these XML files need to be signed using the [XAdES-T](https://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/) protocol. The signature must be included in the XML file.

To do that, I generate a Timestamp Query (TSQ) from the XML file. It is created based on the SHA256 hash of the XML file. After that, I send the TSQ to FreeTSA (Timestamp Authority). The response consists of two elements:

- Response string (string / base64 encoded)
- Response time (integer / unix time)

Now here comes the hard part. The signature must be included in the XML using `dsig:Signature`. Based on the [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/XAdES/#Syntax_for_XAdES_T_form_The_SignatureTimeStamp_element) documentation:

- The SignatureTimeStamp encapsulates the time-stamp over the ds:SignatureValue element.
- The SignatureTimeStamp element contains a single HashDataInfo element that refers to the ds:SignatureValue element of the [XMLDSIG] signature. That is, the input for the timestamp hash computation is the ds:SignatureValue XML element.

I tried the following XML:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <ds:Reference>
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <ds:DigestValue></ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>
       MIIFUDADAgEAMIIFRwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIFODCCBTQCAQMxDzANBglghkgBZQMEAgMFADCCAY4GCyqGSIb3DQEJEAEEoIIBfQSCAXkwggF1AgEBBgQqAwQBMDEwDQYJYIZIAWUDBAIBBQAEIHY4mbyU5g4mM3CRUjMSjILz19kk0jYmuoZSCI6hnXQqAgQAzfxZGA8yMDIxMDgyNTExMzcwN1oBAf8CCHdmnjv+m4i4oIIBEaSCAQ0wggEJMREwDwYDVQQKEwhGcmVlIFRTQTEMMAoGA1UECxMDVFNBMXYwdAYDVQQNE21UaGlzIGNlcnRpZmljYXRlIGRpZ2l0YWxseSBzaWducyBkb2N1bWVudHMgYW5kIHRpbWUgc3RhbXAgcmVxdWVzdHMgbWFkZSB1c2luZyB0aGUgZnJlZXRzYS5vcmcgb25saW5lIHNlcnZpY2VzMRgwFgYDVQQDEw93d3cuZnJlZXRzYS5vcmcxIjAgBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWE2J1c2lsZXphc0BnbWFpbC5jb20xEjAQBgNVBAcTCVd1ZXJ6YnVyZzELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxDzANBgNVBAgTBkJheWVybjGCA4owggOGAgEBMIGjMIGVMREwDwYDVQQKEwhGcmVlIFRTQTEQMA4GA1UECxMHUm9vdCBDQTEYMBYGA1UEAxMPd3d3LmZyZWV0c2Eub3JnMSIwIAYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhNidXNpbGV6YXNAZ21haWwuY29tMRIwEAYDVQQHEwlXdWVyemJ1cmcxDzANBgNVBAgTBkJheWVybjELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUCCQDB6YYWDajpgjANBglghkgBZQMEAgMFAKCBuDAaBgkqhkiG9w0BCQMxDQYLKoZIhvcNAQkQAQQwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTIxMDgyNTExMzcwN1owKwYLKoZIhvcNAQkQAgwxHDAaMBgwFgQUkW2j2GDsyoLjS8WdF5Pn6WiHXxQwTwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMUIEQOATishRq9feRvKy8q5CwPKviUzDLCEu81s7MeGTCrx/mQtcOaGfuSpLefXVXOq1ckfsaxlvY5aZQkW3uaKTDkcwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAEggIAjjHuobwvxwLKdnvRO6YAOWm0JuJ3AU5wXlgZUwYw9hMkQmGyXz+ky2+WvMa4k9OQji+zX4G9xGXzxQg7qLNYkMd+Cfd86eSMqLoTJEatijgDUwdxq0u5JbWUq8RpTjAQFm4mswzg3sbEvsU1y58LJPKRZ0WekKTbBAFjCm4FyH17aWiPh1JS96Tm1on+xhWaoMXJNAyLbguLrQB2TsNQFL19y2wjqCOuomfm4bN/jyeSazmvVH+l8ye1A5xejXx2Lv81w7W1zbrSi7v1/ywnq3utKeMdcqKgLC99jN0ErQkBIhCuP4JvGO5mW/CgQPb+qBWISPgAOBLaYi72204+zl0pTZdpKKNLJaMr6gJFkDIF+ZHmieE5yR9aiQ7SWYYLdEcq5tC8yZjgFJxxyEdxXpBqyp3PkMciBTEeUyRfBlnnP1O+Oe8unqLceGrH/1H4WniDJUXZvra/jLx3T3IdknGn1swHdNMrLETK2vPd646wZfsKTSOqjbzi5ljrS03FsElhxujcrwjGLOs1l/EyAIM0an1lroHnu5n2MH5KLMvPJqjLIqn0jEsxXk8JU+kpqUpcTaTKq24VbvqYO/WeyfD1t2t9ExhPgxAaBf6lm9R7AdbxpWJTl0rP4h3YMq/h5z2U2TYAYXQ3aiXQZR0VvUJbPI22thftdhsNDC0v+fU=
        </ds:SignatureValue>
    </ds:Signature>
```

But the status (according to [this website](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/xmldsig-verifier.html)) is always "invalid".

What is the correct way to append the Timestamp Response to an XML file?

Comment: have you discovered something ? I'm need to do the same! There aren't very docs about this and php.

Comment: Sadly not yet. I've asked the company that required this type of signatures for more information on how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer of an open-source project for creation and validation of electronic signatures.

The problem within your signature is that your signature contains a *ds:Reference* not referencing any content. It shall refer an element within the signature file or a detached document. The *ds:DigestValue* element shall contain digests of the referenced content after applied tranformations.

For a simple XMLDSig signature you can get familiar studying [this specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/).

For extended information about electronic signatures, including advanced and qualified electronic signatures, you can take a look on the [documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html). The project is in Java, but the documentation contains a lot of generic information about the signatures and available formats and ways to create it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution in PHP to work with Xades documents is: https://github.com/bseddon/xml-signer

> Provides signing and verification of XML documents for PHP focussing
> on support for signatures that are compliant with the XAdES
> specification.

I have signed a xml with LTA and timestamping. It´s very easy and well documented!

Thanks to @bseddon!